# how to return a string getting error (type mismatch)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to return a string type but I keep getting a type mismatch, how do I fix this

```
public static string[] count(int a, int b) {
int[] arr = a[b + 1 - a];

for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    arr[i - a] = i;
}          
return arr;
}
```

Comment: you are returing `arr` which is int[] while your method expect `String[]`. 
The fix is change the method signature from `String[]` to `int[]`

Comment: first decide what you need/want: an `int[]` array, a `String[]` array or just a `String`? All 3 are different type of objects. If you need to convert from `int` to `String`: [`Integer.toString(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)) or [`String.valueOf(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int))

Comment: what is 'a' ?? a[b + 1 - a] - array type expected, found int...

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to return a String type but you have an array of int that you need to return, you can use `Arrays.toString(int[])` method to convert and format an int[] array into a String. Also your initialization of the int[] arr was wrong, it should be `new int[size].

```
public static String count(int a, int b) {
    int[] arr = new int[b + 1 - a];

    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        arr[i - a] = i;
    }
    return Arrays.toString(arr);
}
```

Example:

Running the following: `System.out.println(count(1,6));` produces:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Alternatively, you may do an array iteration and format the output as you like using a StringBuffer:

```
   public static String count(int a, int b) {
        int[] arr = new int[b + 1 - a];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            arr[i - a] = i;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            sb.append(i);
            if (i<arr.length-1){
                sb.append(" - ");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

In the above example, each number is separated with - like in

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
```

Comment: thank you so much, but I can't compile the first one

Comment: It was an extra curly bracket pasted. I fixed it :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int[] count(int a, int b) {

    int[] arr = new int[a*(b + 1 - a)];

    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        arr[i - a] = i;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Or

```
public static String[] count(int a, int b) {

    String[] arr = new String[a*(b + 1 - a)];

    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        arr[i - a] = i;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: the 2nd alternative does not pass compilation, you cannot assign an int as an item in a `String` array